# How in RabbitMQ and PHP do task one by one?

Tags: rabbitmq

How do RabbitMQ taks perform one after another Not all the same time,

e.g.
We have 10 task that follow each other.
Task 1 end do task 2 etc..

Answer (score 0):

Set your channel's prefetch (QoS) value to 1. Then, when you consume messages, RabbitMQ will only send one message and will not send more until that one message is acknowledged.

I suggest that you do all of the RabbitMQ tutorials, especially [this one](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-two-php.html).